# Postgresql wont start

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql wont start in ubuntu 16.04,

Please give support.

These are the error log read:

```
2018-10-12 13:42:34 UTC [3371-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2018-10-12 13:42:34 UTC [3371-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2018-10-12 13:42:34 UTC [3376-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2018-10-12 13:42:34 UTC [3373-1] LOG:  shutting down
2018-10-12 13:42:34 UTC [3373-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2018-10-12 13:42:52 UTC [3855-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 
2018-10-12 13:42:34 UTC
2018-10-12 13:42:52 UTC [3855-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound 
protections are now enabled
2018-10-12 13:42:52 UTC [3853-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept 
connections
2018-10-12 13:42:52 UTC [3859-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2018-10-12 13:42:52 UTC [3861-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete 
startup 
packet
```

Comment: Looks like the database is running all right.

Comment: Hi, Usually i used to postgresql from sudo systemctl start postgresql and it starts, but now it doesnt and gives this error, but Im able to start from sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main.service. But what is the difference between two services? and even after starting postgresql@9.5-main.service Im not able to get the database live using pgadmin. Is it necessery to start using postgresql only?

Comment: Examine the respective service files and the diagnostic output from systemd.

Comment: Yes I did, But I would like to know the difference between Postgresql and postgresl@9.5-main.service. Which starts the database, so i can use psql and pgadmin for further connecting the database.